# Sum time from custom string

Tags: c#

I have a time string in a grid like "0 hours 1 minutes".

Now I want to calculate the sum of time.

I can extract this and string using the following code,

```
string timeValue = Regex.Replace(e.FieldValue.ToString(), "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(timeValue, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but I am unable to convert it as time and sum the hours and minutes

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean sum of time? do you mean total minutes?

Comment: You want to convert a string like "5 days 7 hours 41 minutes" to ONE `DateTime` with the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because it expects the hours and the minutes to each have two digits. Instead you can use an regular expression:

```
var timeString = "0 hours 1 minutes";
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<hours>[0-9]+) hours (?<minutes>[0-9]+) minutes$");
var match = regex.Match(timeString);
if (!match.Success)
  // ... handle input error.
var hours = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["hours"].Value);
var minutes = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["minutes"].Value);
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60*hours + minutes);
```

The result is a `TimeSpan` which is the proper type for representing "H hours M minutes" as opposed to a `DateTime` which represents a specific point in time.

Answer (score 3):

If your string is always in that format, you can try it with a pattern and [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.DateTime.TryParseExact);k(TryParseExact);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
string timestring = "0 hours 1 minutes";
string pattern = "H' hours 'm' minutes'";

var dt = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(timestring, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dt))
{
    //success
}
else
{
    //wrong input
}
```